How to Implement a Loading Spinner for HTTP Calls in Angular 17?
I am working on an Angular 17 project and need to implement a loading spinner that displays during HTTP calls. I want the spinner to show when a request or several is made and hide once the response is received. I am looking for a clean and efficient way to achieve this.
Here is what I have so far:
Demo@Stackblitz
app.component.html
@if (loading$ | async) {
  <ng-container>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  </ng-container>
}
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  loading$ = this.loadingService.loading$;

  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {}
}

main.ts
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([networkInterceptorFn])),provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations(), provideAnimationsAsync(), ]
};

network.interceptor.ts
export const networkInterceptorFn: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  let totalRequests = 0;
  let requestsCompleted = 0;

  const loadingService = inject(LoadingService);

  loadingService.show();
  totalRequests++;

  return next(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      requestsCompleted++;

      if (requestsCompleted === totalRequests) {
        loadingService.hide();
        totalRequests = 0;
        requestsCompleted = 0;
      }
    })
  );
};

Function for testing the loading spinner:
  constructor(private taskHttpService: TaskHttpService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchDataTmp();
  }

  fetchDataTmp(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').pipe(
      delay(5000)
    );
  }


You are not registering your NetworkInterceptor into the application
Approach 1: Working with traditional HttpInterceptor class.
import {
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  HttpClient,
  provideHttpClient,
  withInterceptorsFromDi,
} from '@angular/common/http';

import {
  networkInterceptorFn
} from './app/network/network.interceptor';

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NetworkInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
});


Approach 2: Working with HttpInterceptorFn.
Migrate the legacy HttpInterceptor class to HttpInterceptorFn.
export const networkInterceptorFn: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  let totalRequests = 0;
  let requestsCompleted = 0;

  const loadingService = inject(LoadingService);

  loadingService.show();
  totalRequests++;

  return next(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      requestsCompleted++;

      console.log(requestsCompleted, totalRequests);

      if (requestsCompleted === totalRequests) {
        loadingService.hide();
        totalRequests = 0;
        requestsCompleted = 0;
      }
    })
  );
};

import {
  HttpClient,
  provideHttpClient,
  withInterceptors
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  networkInterceptorFn,
} from './app/network/network.interceptor';

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptors([networkInterceptorFn])
    ),
  ],
});

Demo @ StackBlitz
References:

The Refurbished HttpClient in Angular 15 – Standalone APIs and Functional Interceptors

Angular 17: HTTP Interceptors guide



I tried to implement Approach 2 in a project. Unfortunately the spinner isn't shown at all. I can't reproduce the same thing on Stackblitz either. In my question, I have included my current code. Can you look over it and see if you can find what's wrong?

Do you get any errors in the browser console? Try adding a breakpoint to see whether your interceptor and the spinner component hit. Based on what I cloned and modified your StackBlitz link, I includes and import the Angular Material stylesheet (src/styles.scss). Demo

If you still encounter the same issue on your local side, maybe you need to create a new question including the minimal reproducible example in StackBlitz.
